# how to get text value of title attribute of anchor tag in python?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

From below code how to get text of title

```
<td class="col_name" nowrap="nowrap">
<a class="icon" title="refer me">
<img src="https://edu.au/images/icons/silk/vcard.gif" align="top" 
alt="Add to address book">
</a>
Mrs Cal <span class="hl_fcc">B</span>AREN
</td>
```

i.e.,refer me..in python using scrapy?please can any one answer this qusetion? I tried response.css('td.col-name a::attr(text)').extract()..but i'm getting "[]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CSS:

```
response.css('td.col_name a::attr(title)').extract_first()
```

Using XPath:

```
response.xpath('//td[@class="col_name"]/a/@title').extract_first()
```